# Translate WinApi Crypt to the .NET Framework System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, winapi, encryption

I would like to ask for a help with refactoring following C# code.

The target is to remove all external WinApi call and replace them with methods from System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

```
private static IntPtr GenerateKey(IntPtr hCryptProv, byte[] keyData)
{
    var hHash = IntPtr.Zero;
    Win32.CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, Win32.CALG_MD5, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref hHash);
    var len = (uint)keyData.Length;
    Win32.CryptHashData(hHash, keyData, len, 0);
    var hKey = IntPtr.Zero;
    Win32.CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, Win32.CALG_3DES, hHash, 0, ref hKey);
    if (hHash != IntPtr.Zero) Win32.CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    return hKey;
}

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] dataToEncrypt)
{                        
    var keyData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{2B9B4443-74CE-42A8-8803-076B136B5967}");
    var size = (uint)dataToEncrypt.Length;                
    var buffer = new byte[size * 2];
    Array.Copy(dataToEncrypt, 0, buffer, 0, size);
    var hCryptProv = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool gotcsp = Win32.CryptAcquireContext(ref hCryptProv, null, null, Win32.PROV_RSA_FULL, Win32.CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | Win32.CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET);
    if (!gotcsp)
    {
        Win32.CryptAcquireContext(ref hCryptProv, null, null, Win32.PROV_RSA_FULL, Win32.CRYPT_NEWKEYSET | Win32.CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | Win32.CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET);
    }                        

    if (hCryptProv == IntPtr.Zero) return null;

    var hKey = GenerateKey(hCryptProv, keyData);
    Win32.CryptEncrypt(hKey, IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0, buffer, ref size, size*2);
    var encryptedData = new byte[size];
    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, encryptedData, 0, size);
    if (hKey != IntPtr.Zero) Win32.CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    if (hCryptProv != IntPtr.Zero) Win32.CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);            
    return encryptedData;
}
/// <summary>
/// WinAPI Imports
/// </summary>
internal class Win32
{
    public const uint PROV_RSA_FULL = 1;
    public const uint NTE_BAD_KEYSET = 0x80090016;
    public const uint CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = 0x00000008;
    public const uint CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = 0xF0000000;
    public const uint CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET = 0x00000020;

    public const uint ALG_CLASS_HASH = (4 << 13);
    public const uint ALG_SID_MD5 = 3;
    public const uint CALG_MD5 = (ALG_CLASS_HASH | ALG_SID_MD5);
    public const uint ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT = (3 << 13);
    public const uint ALG_TYPE_BLOCK = (3 << 9);
    public const uint ALG_SID_3DES = 3;
    public const uint CALG_3DES = (ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT | ALG_TYPE_BLOCK | ALG_SID_3DES);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(ref IntPtr hProv, string pszContainer, string pszProvider, uint dwProvType, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptReleaseContext(IntPtr hProv, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptDestroyKey(IntPtr hKey);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptCreateHash(IntPtr hProv, uint Algid, IntPtr hKey, uint dwFlags, ref IntPtr hHash);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptHashData(IntPtr hHash, [In, Out] byte[] pbData, uint dwDataLen, uint dwSize);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptDestroyHash(IntPtr hHash);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptDeriveKey(IntPtr hProv, uint Algid, IntPtr hHash, uint dwFlags, ref IntPtr hKey);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptEncrypt(IntPtr hKey, IntPtr hHash, int Final, uint dwFlags, [In, Out] byte[] pbData, ref uint pdwDataLen, uint dwBufLen);
}
```

I have tried different combinations, options and encryption providers, and there is no problem to create similar method using System.Security.Cryptography, but the problem is that I need a method that will replace a code. 
That means that with the same data passed for encryption I must get the same result. And here is a problem. My knowledge of encryption are definitely is not so deep to take into account all nuances of this method.

Can you help me with this issue? I don't mean to give me a link to encryption tutorial, but to tell me what methods with which options I should to use.

**[2017-03-28 11:27GMT] Additional information**:

I really do not think that it will helps, but there is one of my experimental code that I finish with:

```
public static List<byte> Encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt)
{
    var databytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{2B9B4443-74CE-42A8-8803-076B136B5967}");
    var hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    var keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(databytes);
    hashmd5.Clear();            
    var pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(keyArray, new byte[0]);
    var hashKey = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "MD5", 0, new byte[8]);

    var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = hashKey;
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    var cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();            
    var resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
    tdes.Clear();
    return resultArray.ToList();
}
```

There was many other variations but no any that give me correct result:

**Source data:**

```
private byte[] dataToEncrypt = {224,111,176,138,238,238,238,239,115,109,201,144,89,58,161,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

**Original function reurns:**

```
private byte[] originalResult = {31,173,65,161,199,249,73,200,210,74,156,21,36,160,94,137,71,205,15,206,99,105,40,83};
```

**Sample function returns:**

```
private byte[] sampleResult = {211,29,187,125,82,9,240,177,199,133,135,7,132,166,166,164,189,36,126,186,104,79,53,159};
```

Comment: *"I have tried different combinations, options and encryption providers, and there is no problem to create similar method using System.Security.Cryptography"* -  If you tried it, then you should be able to show some of it. Please [edit] your question to include the missing code along with inputs outputs and expected outputs (in short an [MCVE](/help/mcve)).

Comment: at least post some sample data to encrypt and the result, because it is impossible to verify this. Also it seems that the key derivation is not FIPS compliant but basically just hashes a string with md5 then passes that as data for 3DES key derivation, and then you seem to RSA encrypt this data.

Comment: @zaitsman No, the code he posted works... So it is possible to encrypt and binary compare. Sadly the documentation of RSA on .NET is quite sparse.

Comment: @xanatos there is plenty of RSA doco and the interfaces are really simple. And yes, the code from OP probably works. I would like to see some data and keys that the OP is encrypting with, so i can write corresponding code. Of course, i could probably copy paste the whole listing and run it against some of my arbitrary data, but my experience with posts like this is that the response usually is 'oh well it doesnt work for MY data' :)

Comment: I add some additional data as you requested.
Thank you, for quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost at least one hour because I thought your code was using RSA (I was mislead by the `PROV_RSA_FULL`)... In truth it is only doing 3DES encryption...

```
var keyData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{2B9B4443-74CE-42A8-8803-076B136B5967}");
byte[] key;

using (PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(keyData, null))
{
    key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "MD5", 0, new byte[8]);
    //Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(key));
}

using (var prov = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    using (var encryptor = prov.CreateEncryptor(key, new byte[8]))
    {
        byte[] encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
        //Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(encrypted));
    }
}
```

Just out of curiousity I'll post a modified version of the original C# code... I wanted to debug a little the generated key, but it is complex to export it in CryptoAPI, and then the original code wasn't like I would have written it :-)

```
private static IntPtr GenerateKey(IntPtr hProv, byte[] keyData)
{
    var hHash = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        bool check = Win32.CryptCreateHash(hProv, Win32.CALG_MD5, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out hHash);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        check = Win32.CryptHashData(hHash, keyData, keyData.Length, 0);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        IntPtr hKey;

        check = Win32.CryptDeriveKey(hProv, Win32.CALG_3DES, hHash, Win32.CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, out hKey);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return hKey;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hHash != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32.CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainText)
{
    var keyData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{2B9B4443-74CE-42A8-8803-076B136B5967}");

    IntPtr hCryptProv = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hKey = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        bool check = Win32.CryptAcquireContext(out hCryptProv, null, null, Win32.PROV_RSA_FULL, Win32.CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | Win32.CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET);

        if (!check)
        {
            check = Win32.CryptAcquireContext(out hCryptProv, null, null, Win32.PROV_RSA_FULL, Win32.CRYPT_NEWKEYSET | Win32.CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | Win32.CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET);

            if (!check)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }

        hKey = GenerateKey(hCryptProv, keyData);

        //byte[] key = ExportSymmetricKey(hCryptProv, hKey);
        //Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(key));

        var size = plainText.Length;
        check = Win32.CryptEncrypt(hKey, IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0, null, ref size, 0);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        var cypherText = new byte[size];

        Array.Copy(plainText, cypherText, plainText.Length);

        size = plainText.Length;

        check = Win32.CryptEncrypt(hKey, IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0, cypherText, ref size, cypherText.Length);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return cypherText;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hKey != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32.CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        }

        if (hCryptProv != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32.CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        }
    }
}

// Based on https://books.google.it/books?id=aL3P3eJdiREC&pg=PT271&lpg=PT271&dq=PROV_RSA_FULL+CryptEncrypt&source=bl&ots=STsuConTHr&sig=W-BWwch8aZ-RqFb8N67rMHTrqYc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit2qKnlfvSAhWCtRQKHbL9BbQQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=PROV_RSA_FULL%20CryptEncrypt&f=false
// Page 248
private static byte[] ExportSymmetricKey(IntPtr hProv, IntPtr hKey)
{
    IntPtr hExpKey = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        bool check = Win32.CryptGenKey(hProv, 1 /* AT_KEYEXCHANGE */, 1024 << 16, out hExpKey);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        int size = 0;
        check = Win32.CryptExportKey(hKey, hExpKey, 1 /* SIMPLEBLOB */, 0, null, ref size);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        var bytes = new byte[size];

        check = Win32.CryptExportKey(hKey, hExpKey, 1 /* SIMPLEBLOB */, 0, bytes, ref size);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        // The next lines could be optimized by using a CryptDecrypt 
        // that accepts a IntPtr and adding directly 12 to the ref bytes
        // instead of copying around the byte array

        // 12 == sizeof(BLOBHEADER) + sizeof(ALG_ID)
        var bytes2 = new byte[size - 12];

        Array.Copy(bytes, 12, bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);

        bytes = bytes2;
        bytes2 = null;

        check = Win32.CryptDecrypt(hExpKey, IntPtr.Zero, true, 0, bytes, ref size);

        if (!check)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        Array.Resize(ref bytes, size);

        return bytes;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hExpKey != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32.CryptDestroyKey(hExpKey);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// WinAPI Imports
/// </summary>
internal class Win32
{
    public const uint PROV_RSA_FULL = 1;
    public const uint NTE_BAD_KEYSET = 0x80090016;
    public const uint CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = 0x00000008;
    public const uint CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT = 0xF0000000;
    public const uint CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET = 0x00000020;

    public const uint CRYPT_EXPORTABLE = 1;

    public const uint ALG_CLASS_HASH = (4 << 13);
    public const uint ALG_SID_MD5 = 3;
    public const uint CALG_MD5 = (ALG_CLASS_HASH | ALG_SID_MD5);
    public const uint ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT = (3 << 13);
    public const uint ALG_TYPE_BLOCK = (3 << 9);
    public const uint ALG_SID_3DES = 3;
    public const uint CALG_3DES = (ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT | ALG_TYPE_BLOCK | ALG_SID_3DES);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(out IntPtr hProv, string pszContainer, string pszProvider, uint dwProvType, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptReleaseContext(IntPtr hProv, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptDestroyKey(IntPtr hKey);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptCreateHash(IntPtr hProv, uint Algid, IntPtr hKey, uint dwFlags, out IntPtr hHash);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptHashData(IntPtr hHash, [In, Out] byte[] pbData, int dwDataLen, uint dwSize);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptDestroyHash(IntPtr hHash);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptDeriveKey(IntPtr hProv, uint Algid, IntPtr hHash, uint dwFlags, out IntPtr hKey);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptGenKey(IntPtr hProv, uint Algid, uint dwFlags, out IntPtr hKey);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptEncrypt(IntPtr hKey, IntPtr hHash, int final, uint dwFlags, [In, Out] byte[] pbData, ref int pdwDataLen, int dwBufLen);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptExportKey(IntPtr hKey, IntPtr hExpKey, uint dwBlobType, uint dwFlags, [Out] byte[] pbData, ref int pdwDataLen);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptGetKeyParam(IntPtr hKey, uint dwParam, [Out] byte[] pbData, ref int pdwDataLen, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptDecrypt(IntPtr hKey, IntPtr hHash, bool final, uint dwFlags, [In, Out] byte[] pbData, ref int pdwDataLen);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
By the way, I was mislead with this keys as well, only one difference - you spent an hour and was able to get a right variant, but I was spent just 8 and stuck on it... Thank you again for working solution and additional thanks for reference on a good book about encryption.